# created a tag and wiki; now it's gone

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I created the tag [koken](/questions/tagged/koken) (and its tag wiki) for [a question about koken themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635929/how-to-make-custom-templates-in-koken).

Someone thoughtfully removed the [koken](/questions/tagged/koken) tag from my question and replaced it with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [html](/questions/tagged/html), perhaps thinking those tags would get more traffic to my question.

I retagged the question as [koken](/questions/tagged/koken) (as I was able to answer the question using koken framework) and note that the Koken tag wiki has vanished.

I can understand why my question was untagged koken, but I wonder why the koken tag wiki vanished.  Was it automagically erased because no questions had that tag?

Comment: IIRC there is a script that cleans up tags with 0 usage.

Comment: You're right, Eran.  In this case, however, I specifically want a koken solution, as I was already able to solve it with javascript (as mentioned in the question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags with no questions are purged every day, so by the time the daily job ran your question didn't have the [koken](/questions/tagged/koken) tag anymore. When you re-added it the tag was created afresh, hence the missing wiki.